# Raise PropertyChanged event on a specific object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

So i have a class (called DataClass) that handles some application data. The class implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Currently i have 2 static instances of this class (DataRx and DataTx) that i created in the ViewModelBase class and I want to raise the `PropertyChanged` events on each class separately. 
On the ViewModel the implementation is:

```
DataRx.PropertyChanged += DataRx_PropertyChanged;
DataTx.PropertyChanged += DataTx_PropertyChanged;
```

The issue is that while I'm changing any of the DataClass properties of DataRx object both `DataRx_PropertyChanged` and `DataTx_PropertyChanged` methods are activated instead of just `DataRx_PropertyChanged`.

How can I activate the event just on the desired object?

EDIT:

The Interface implementation is as follows:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string name = null)
{
    if (Equals(field, value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    field = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(name);
    return true;
 }  
 protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = null)
 {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
 }
```

Comment: When setting a property on one instance of DataClass fires the PropertyChanged event of the other instance, there is something wrong with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably declaring the PropertyChangedEventHandler static.

The correct implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface should look similar to this:

```
private string myProperty;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

// This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
// The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
// parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return myProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        if (myProperty != value)
        {
            myProperty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```